# Firebase Firestore data is not showing in my map function for React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fill my state array with my document data from my database. I am getting no errors, however I am not getting any of my data to display. In my firestore database I have a collection "messages" and then two auto ID document with a title and message as fields in each. The data is not showing at all.

```
export class WindowUplifting extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arra: null,
      items: [],
    };
    this.state.messagesEndRef = React.createRef();
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    //this.setState({ groupId: this.props.currentGroup.id });
    this.scrollToBottom();
    // this.getListner();

    let itemArr = [];

    db.collection("messages")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        //Notice the arrow funtion which bind `this` automatically.
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          itemArr.push(doc.data());
        });
        this.setState({ items: itemArr }); //set data in state here
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.currentGroup) {
      this.setState({ groupId: nextProps.currentGroup.id });
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.unsubscribe != null) this.state.unsubscribe(); //remove listener
  }

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.state.messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const items = this.state.items;
    return (
      <div className={classes.welcome}>
        <ul className={classes.chatList}>
          {items.length >= 0 &&
            items.map((item) => (
              <li>
                <h1> {item.title}</h1>

                <Divider style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 10 }} />
                <p>{item.body}</p>
              </li>
            ))}
```

......

Comment: You have used `async` in `async componentDidMount()` but not used await. Check on that. back to your question, you can try checking the DB values are retrieving by adding a simple console.log inside `querySnapshot.forEach`.

Comment: If you log the values of the docs as Doug mentions above, do you get the expected data?